# Choose the kth choice of choosing n things out of m

Tags: combinatorics

Say I have a list, L, of m things.

I want to pick n things out of the total of m things in the list.

Suppose there are W ways of doing this. I want to choose the k<sup>th</sup> way where k is in the range 1..W.

i.e. my function is this:

```
ChooseKthChoiceOf(L,n,k){
   ....
}
```

Any good algorithms for this?

Answer (score 6):

This is called [unranking](https://oeis.org/wiki/Ranking_and_unranking_functions).  The [combinatorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system) provides a clean solution to this particular problem.

See also https://computationalcombinatorics.wordpress.com/2012/09/10/ranking-and-unranking-of-combinations-and-permutations/ for further reading.

Comment: Yes, that seems right. I'm having a little difficulty trying to discern this ranking/unranking algorithm however. Seems like you would need a lot if statements!